# Pyqt Display Video Thumbnail At Given Time Line

Tags: python, video, pyqt, media-player, pyside6

I have a basic pyqt video player but I want the video time line background to be pictures of what is happing at that time of the video, what will I have to use to do this efficiently? Here is the basic player:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput

class PyVideoPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PyVideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput()

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_play.svg"))
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.volumeButton = QPushButton()
        self.volumeButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_volume.svg"))
        self.volumeButton.clicked.connect(self.showVolumeSlider)

        self.volumeSlider = QSlider(orientation=Qt.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.volumeSlider.setValue(self.audioOutput.volume() * 100)
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.volumeSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setVolume)
        self.volumeSlider.hide()

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(orientation=Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.timeLabel = QLabel()
        self.timeLabel.setStyleSheet("color: #4f5b6e; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;")

        # Set up the layout
        videoLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        videoLayout.addWidget(videoWidget, stretch=1)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.volumeButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.volumeSlider)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.timeLabel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(videoLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)

        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.errorOccurred.connect(self.handleError)

    def setMedia(self, fileName):
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))
        self.mediaPlayer.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
        self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.play()

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_pause.svg"))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_play.svg"))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeLabel.setText(f"{position // 60000:02}:{(position // 1000) % 60:02} / {self.mediaPlayer.duration() // 60000:02}:{(self.mediaPlayer.duration() // 1000) % 60:02}")

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def setVolume(self, volume):
        self.audioOutput.setVolume(volume / 100)

    def showVolumeSlider(self):
        if self.volumeSlider.isHidden():
            self.volumeSlider.show()
        else:
            self.volumeSlider.hide()

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        print("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PyVideoPlayer()
    ex.setMedia("your_video.mp4")  # Replace with your video file path
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried different things such as using QVideoFrame and then converting to an image using QImage but unsure if its supposed to be used like this.

This is an example of how I want the time line to look:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: The code for the player is almost irrelevant, since it doesn't include anything about what you want to do. Instead, show us your attempts of using QVideoFrame by providing a [mre] and explain your doubts or possible issues; note that it must be *both* minimal **and** reproducible, so we must have a working code (that we could possibly copy/paste/run) without anything that is not relevant to the problem (such as volume control, timestamp display, style/icon, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [QVideoSink](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtMultimedia/QVideoSink.html) with the `videoFrame()` function to get frame data from `QtMultimedia` or in another way you can use `cv2` (Open CV) to create thumbnails.

full code:

```py
import sys
import cv2
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PySide6.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QAudioOutput


class TimeLineImageWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TimeLineImageWidget, self).__init__()
        self.image = QLabel()
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.resize(200, 250)
        self.setStyleSheet("background: white;")
        self.lay.addWidget(self.image)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.show()

    def setImage(self, img):
        pixmap = QPixmap(img)
        self.image.setPixmap(
            pixmap.scaled(200, 150, Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        )

    def destry(self):
        self.image.close()


class PyVideoPlayer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PyVideoPlayer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput()

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()

        self.thumbnail_widget = QWidget()
        self.thumbnail = QHBoxLayout()
        self.thumbnail_widget.setLayout(self.thumbnail)

        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_play.svg"))
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.volumeButton = QPushButton()
        self.volumeButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_volume.svg"))
        self.volumeButton.clicked.connect(self.showVolumeSlider)

        self.volumeSlider = QSlider(orientation=Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.volumeSlider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.volumeSlider.setValue(int(self.audioOutput.volume() * 100))
        self.volumeSlider.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.volumeSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setVolume)
        self.volumeSlider.hide()

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(orientation=Qt.Orientation.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.timeLabel = QLabel()
        self.timeLabel.setStyleSheet(
            "color: #4f5b6e; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 9pt; font-weight: bold;"
        )

        self.timeLineImage = TimeLineImageWidget()

        # Set up the layout
        videoLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        videoLayout.addWidget(videoWidget, stretch=1)

        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.volumeButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.volumeSlider)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.timeLabel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(videoLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.timeLineImage)
        layout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)
        layout.addWidget(self.thumbnail_widget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)

        layout.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.playbackStateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.errorOccurred.connect(self.handleError)

    def setMedia(self, fileName):
        self.generate_thumbnail_previews(fileName)
        self.mediaPlayer.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))
        self.mediaPlayer.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput)
        self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.play()

    def generate_thumbnail_previews(self, url):
        video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
        total_frames = int(video_capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        interval = total_frames // 10  # Generate 10 thumbnails
        thumbnails = []

        for i in range(10):
            video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, i * interval)
            ret, frame = video_capture.read()
            if ret:
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert frame to RGB
                height, width, _ = frame.shape
                img = QPixmap.fromImage(
                    QImage(frame.data, width, height, width * 3, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                )
                thumbnails.append(img)

        video_capture.release()

        # Display thumbnails on the slider
        for i, thumbnail in enumerate(thumbnails):
            label = QLabel()
            label.setPixmap(thumbnail.scaled(100, 100, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            self.thumbnail.addWidget(label)

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_pause.svg"))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(QIcon("gui/images/svg_icons/icon_play.svg"))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeLabel.setText(
            f"{position // 60000:02}:{(position // 1000) % 60:02} / {self.mediaPlayer.duration() // 60000:02}:{(self.mediaPlayer.duration() // 1000) % 60:02}"
        )
        # update image timeline
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() == QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            sink = self.mediaPlayer.videoSink()
            self.timeLineImage.setImage(sink.videoFrame().toImage())

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)
        # update image timeline
        if self.mediaPlayer.playbackState() != QMediaPlayer.PlaybackState.PlayingState:
            sink = self.mediaPlayer.videoSink()
            self.timeLineImage.setImage(sink.videoFrame().toImage())

    def setVolume(self, volume):
        self.audioOutput.setVolume(volume / 100)

    def showVolumeSlider(self):
        if self.volumeSlider.isHidden():
            self.volumeSlider.show()
        else:
            self.volumeSlider.hide()

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        print("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = PyVideoPlayer()
        ex.resize(720, 480)
        ex.setMedia("video file.mp4")  # Replace with your video file path
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. They want to display a preview thumbnail at different time positions and UI coordinates depending on a given timeline position, independently from the actual player position, similarly to the thumbnails shown in YouTube and other video apps when hovering/moving the mouse above the slider. Your code instead just shows an image of the **current** player position while playing back the content.

Comment: Yes I know that, the code is just an example, for the problem can be solved that way, for the timeline as you mean, like youtube where it displays a popup image when you move the slider position. You need to add `Popup Flag` and for thumbnails can be generated with Open CV library in the updated code.

Comment: Thanks Duckzio, that was exactly what I was looking to do!